# Redis instantly saving to disk even though configured not to

Tags: redis

I'm using redis 2.8 with the default redis.conf file.

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

appendonly no
```

I tried setting a key and immediately restarted the server (within few seconds). Upon restarting the key is persisting.

I don't understand how that's happening. According to the default configuration the key should be saved to disk only if 10000 keys are changed within 60 seconds.

Even tried to set

```
appendfsync no
```

Still the key is persisting.

Comment: I had been using Redis as Django Cache. The default timeout for Django cache is 300. So even though Redis is set not to persist, Django cache framework would set the expiry to 300 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `save` configuration directive is set (to any value), Redis will persist the dataset to RDB before shutting down. This behavior can be overridden by calling the [`SHUTDOWN`](https://redis.io/commands/shutdown) command with the optional `NOSAVE` subcommand.